# BytePointer and ClsUtil classes missing from Intellij Library version IntelliJ IDEA IU-181.4203.550

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij Version IntelliJ IDEA IU-181.4203.550

```
import com.intellij.util.cls.BytePointer; // Not working
import com.intellij.util.cls.ClsUtil; // Not working
```

I can see that BytePointer and ClsUtil classes are missing from Intellij version specified above, is there any other classes which has been replaced instead of this?

I am migrating a plugin from Idea 13.0.2 to new version of intellij and facing some compilation errors.

Comment: Please post the exact full snippet of the code you're trying to port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still find these classes in historic branches ([BytePointer](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/131/platform/util/src/com/intellij/util/cls/BytePointer.java), [ClsUtil](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/131/platform/util/src/com/intellij/util/cls/ClsUtil.java)). They are licensed under Apache 2, so you may just include them into your plugin.

Alternatively, you may rewrite the code using `java.io.DataInputStream` and ASM classes (`org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes`, `org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.Type` etc.)

Comment: This is what I did, copied the class from other sources, and pasted it in plugin.